# Tooltip on absolute element using react-tippy ReactJS

Tags: css, reactjs, tooltip, absolute

I am using this library https://tvkhoa.github.io/testlib/ to make some nice tooltip in my React App.
I use that code in my own component which look like this

```
const Tooltip = ({className, children, text, placement = 'bottom', isDisabled = false}) => {
    return (
            <ReactTippyTooltip className={className} html={<span>{text}</span>}
                               theme="dark" position={placement} arrow={true} arrowSize="regular"
                               animation="shift" hideDelay={300}>
                {children}
            </ReactTippyTooltip>
    );
};
```

On basic elements such as simple images or buttons, everything works fine. But in some cases, I need to have a tooltip on an absolute element. For example on an InfoButton which overlaps an image.

```
<div className="relative"> <!-- container -->
   <img /> 
   <Tooltip> <!-- tooltip container -->
      <InfoButton className="absolute top-0 left-0"> 
   </Tooltip>
</div>
```

**But I noticed that the tooltip appears bellow the image, instead of bellow the InfoButton**.
If I have a look with the devtool, I can see that my InfoButton is inside a div that represents ReactTippyTooltip, and that div is 0*0 and is positionned bellow the image in the DOM. This is because only its content (InfoButton) is absolute and positionned inside the image. It can be summarized by the following image [image: situation]
I put a className to ReactTippyTooltip as a workaround and I made it absolute as well. Like this my tooltip is at the right place, but I feel like there is something wrong with what I am my doing.
Has anyone encountered some issues with tooltip on absolute elements ?
Can I do some better code with the library I am using ?
Does it exist some react tooltip library that use reference of the element to display the tooltip ?

Comment: I'm not using that library, but here an idea, you can add after element on the button, set height and width 100%, position relative, although we not gonna see it, it there and Tooltip will base on that relative to display. Try if it works or not?

Comment: I partially get the idea. What do you mean exactly by "add after element on the button" ? Is it via CSS with **::after** ?

Comment: Yes, it is. That way we have a relative element so the tooltip will display base on that, and because it right below the button so the tooltip will be there too.

Comment: I just tried it, but It actually does not make it. After élement is now on top of InfoBtn (invisible) but the tooltip is still applied to the container div (ReactTippyTooltip ) which is still 0*0 and positionned after the image